# Thymeleaf not redirecting to index.html

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have added Thymeleaf to my Spring Boot project.

I have created a HTML file in `/resources/templates/index.html`

I have added a method to my @RestController:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    // irreveland code here
    return "index";
}
```

It seems that this method kinda works, but instead of redirecting me to `http://localhost:8080/templates/index.html` I have a white page with a word "index" on it (no html in sources, just the word **index**)

I have tried to put the index.html page to /resources/static and /resources for test purposes - no effort.

What could go wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You annotated your controller with `@RestController`, which means that all return values are treated as response bodies (`@ResponseBody`). That means that your string `"index"` is treated as such, and not as a view.

In order to use the MVC approach, where `"index"` refers to a view called `index.html`, you should use the `@Controller` annotation.

Comment: This is it... I was testing my API using RestController to play with postman, and I forgot to change it. With Controller annotation it works like a charm

Comment: In the above situation, you would only see word "index" printed in the browser since `@RestContoller` is a combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`. This simply returns the object and object data which is directly written into HTTP response as text. In your case, you are probably creating a map and then providing which view to use to display the results. This would need `@Controller` annotation. For more please read <https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/08/difference-between-restcontroller-and-controller-annotations-spring-mvc-rest.html.>